# How to fix Zombie Object throwing 'EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION' when calling show window

Tags: objective-c, malloc, zombie-process, exc-bad-instruction

My program visualizes and graphs the currents of simulated neurons and how they interact. When we try to add more than two neurons to be visualized 2/3 times the program crashes with a EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION error on the line which should show a window which can set the parameters of individual neurons.

I have tried turning on Zombie Objects to get more information but then the program no longer crashes so I can't get any more information. The issue is clearly a Zombie Object problem I just can't figure out how to solve it.

```
- (IBAction) showParameterSetterWindow:(id)sender
{

    if (parameterSetter == nil)
    {
        ParameterSetter *newParameterSetter = [[ParameterSetter alloc] initWithDefaultWindowNib];
        [self setParameterSetter:newParameterSetter];
    }

    [[self parameterSetter].window orderFront:self]; //Error appears here

} // showSynapseWindow
```

The error at each location is:

> ```
> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
> ```

In the debug window this is printed:

> ```
> 019-08-05 15:15:04.306293-0400 RoboLobsterSimu[1680:175553] Parameter Setter AwakeFromNIB completed
> RoboLobsterSimu(1680,0x10013e5c0) malloc: Heap corruption detected, free list is damaged at 0x60001412b1f0
> *** Incorrect guard value: 3
> RoboLobsterSimu(1680,0x10013e5c0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
> RoboLobsterSimu(1680,0x10013e5c0) malloc: Heap corruption detected, free list is damaged at 0x600014128020
> *** Incorrect guard value: 13830554455654793216
> RoboLobsterSimu(1680,0x10013e5c0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
> warning: could not execute support code to read Objective-C class data in the process. This may reduce the quality of type information available.
> ```

Let me know if you need any more information to solve the problem, thank you!
Here are the codes segments I was asked to add. Thank you very much!

Here is initWithDefaultWindowNib

```
- (id)initWithDefaultWindowNib
{
/*  AnalysisWindowController *awc;
    awc = [super initWithWindowNibName:@"AnalysisWindowController"];
    if (!awc)
        {
        NSLog(@"Warning! Could not load AnalysisWindowController file.\n");
        }
    else
        {
        NSLog(@"AnalysisWindowController Nib Loaded");
        [awc logAnalysisWindowController];
        }
    return awc;
 */
    if (!self){
    self = [super initWithWindowNibName:@"AnalysisWindowController"];
    if (self)
        {
        [self logAnalysisWindowController];
        }
    else
        {
        NSLog(@"Warning! Could not load AnalysisWindowController nib.\n");
        }
    }
    return self;

 }
```

And it is also called in another file like this:

```
- (id)initWithDefaultWindowNib
{
  if (!self){
        self = [super initWithWindowNibName:@"ParameterSetter"];
        if (self)
        {
             NSLog(@"Executing InitWithDefaultWIndowNib in Parameter Setter");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Warning! Could not load ParameterSetter nib.\n");
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

And for setParameterSetter the proffessor said "That’s what the synthesize operator does. it creates a setter and getter. setParameterSetter is created as the setter for ParameterSetter. ParameterSetter is the getter"

Either way, here is parameterSetter:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) ParameterSetter          *parameterSetter;
- (ParameterSetter *)parameterSetter
{
    if (parameterSetter == nil)
    {
        ParameterSetter *newParameterSetter = [[ParameterSetter alloc] initWithDefaultWindowNib];
        [self setParameterSetter:newParameterSetter];
    }
    return parameterSetter;
}
```

Thanks again

Comment: Please post the code of `initWithDefaultWindowNib`, `setParameterSetter:` and `parameterSetter`. Do you keep a strong reference to the `ParameterSetter`?

Comment: Just did, thank you

Comment: Why `if (!self){`? `self` shouldn't be `nil`.

Comment: @Willeke Truthfully I’m not certain, I wrote the C portion of this this program and the old assistant wrote the Objective-C before moving on. I tried changing it to if (self) {... and the crash still occurs, and I tried commenting out that line completely along with its end bracket and the error still occurred. Annoyingly the error only occurs 1/5 times. Any suggestions? Let me know if you need to see more code, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone finds this I know this is super unhelpful but I just scrapped the entire parameter setter window and rebuilt it being careful to check for errors at each step and feature added.